# Replace missing value in a row if there's a match in two columns from another row using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I'm working on a data analysis project and I have the following dataframe that looks like this.

| id | store | long | lat |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 | -4 |
| 2 | **NaN** | **2** | **3** |
| 3 | C | 4 | 5 |
| 4 | **D** | **2** | **3** |

I want to fill the missing value NaN in the 'store' column with the one in row with id 4, given that row with id 2 and 4 have the same values in the 'long' and 'lat' columns, so the output should look like this

| id | store | long | lat |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 | -4 |
| 2 | **D** | **2** | **3** |
| 3 | C | 4 | 5 |
| 4 | **D** | **2** | **3** |

I want to do this for a long dataframe (almost a million rows), so I don't know the row ids that have the same 'long' and 'lat' values.

I'm working on Python using Pandas. I've only come up with this solution using *for loops* and iterrows(), which is super slow

```
df_missing_names = df[df['store'].isna()] #rows that have missing names
df_with_names = df[df['store'].notna()] #rows that don't have missing names

for indx, row in df_missing_names.iterrows(): #run through all the rows that don't have names

    for indx_j, row_j in df_with_names.iterrows(): #run through all the rows that have names

        if (row.lat == row_j.lat) & (row.long == row_j.long): #if both lat and long values match
            df[indx, 'store'] = row_j.store #then update name of the row in the original dataframe
```

Is there a faster way to do this using built in functions on Pandas? Thanks for the help

Comment: `df['store'] = df['store'].fillna(df.groupby(['long','lat'])['store'].transform('first'))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
df['store'] = df.groupby(['long', 'lat'], sort=False).bfill()['store']
```

Output:

```
   id store  long  lat
0   1     A     1   -4
1   2     D     2    3
2   3     C     4    5
3   4     D     2    3
```